# Error in Rcircos plot package

Tags: r

I've been trying to use RCircos package for weeks and every time I run the code I get an error that I cannot understand. 
my data:

```
Chr  Start    End                                    Gene
1 chr1 801943 801943 LOC643837(dist=12203),FAM41C(dist=1508)
2 chr1 802289 802289 LOC643837(dist=12549),FAM41C(dist=1162)
3 chr1 802300 802300 LOC643837(dist=12560),FAM41C(dist=1151)
4 chr1 802320 802320 LOC643837(dist=12580),FAM41C(dist=1131)
5 chr1 802338 802338 LOC643837(dist=12598),FAM41C(dist=1113)
6 chr1 802381 802381 LOC643837(dist=12641),FAM41C(dist=1070)
```

my code:

```
> library(RCircos)   
> setwd("~/Desktop/")   
> data("UCSC.HG19.Human.CytoBandIdeogram")    
> my_data <-read.csv("data.csv", header = T, sep="\t")     
> cyto.info <-UCSC.HG19.Human.CytoBandIdeogram   
> tracks.inside <-10
> tracks.outside <-0    
>chr.exclude <-NULL   
> RCircos.Set.Core.Components ( cyto.info, chr.exclude, tracks.inside,tracks.outside)
> pdf("Rcircos.pdf", height = 8, width = 8, compress = T) 
> RCircos.Set.Plot.Area()  
> RCircos.Chromosome.Ideogram.Plot()  
>name.col <-4  
> side <-"in"
> track.num <-1
> RCircos.Gene.Connector.Plot(genomic.data= my_data, track.num =
track.num,  side=side)   track.num <-2 
> RCircos.Gene.Name.Plot(my_data, name.col,track.num, side)
> dev.off()
```

The error I am getting is : "Error in RCircos.Validate.Genomic.Data(genomic.data = my_data, plot.type = c("plot"), : Some chromosomes in plot data is not in ideogram."

I have tried changing the cytoband ideogram and use the hg38 still nothing, I checked my data and has all the chromosomes in, the start and end positions are withing the range of the cytoband info found from UCSC. I have read most of the documentation that there is for this package but still nothing, there is a simple solution I am sure of it, but I cannot figure this out. I would much appreciate if anyone could explain to me where the error is and what should I try.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. You can fix this issue by changing your Ideogram. As is clear in your codes you are using this ideogram `UCSC.HG19.Human.CytoBandIdeogram` which is an old version of human genome annotation. If you use this one I hope you will workaround this issue:

```
data("UCSC.HG38.Human.CytoBandIdeogram")    
cyto.info <- UCSC.HG38.Human.CytoBandIdeogram;
```

Best,
Mehdi